# tycho plugin + maven-dependency-plugin: copy dependencies from local projects instead repositories

Tags: maven

Main Goal: deploy a project as jar *and* eclipse-plugin

current state: project builds fine as jar package

Now i want to create a second project which wraps the jar project as eclipse plugin

- use tycho-maven-plugin to create eclipse-plugin
- add the jar of the original project (with copy-dependency)
- add an Activator
- export packages from jar
- create correct MANIFEST.MF

i tried to copy the jar with copy-dependencies bound to create-resources. This works as long the jar is found in repository, but the local project gets ignored.
This results in a build failure since the jar is not found.

Is it possible to tell copy-dependencies to take the jar from the target directory of the project? Or should i use some other method than using tycho?

Edit:

I solved my problem with 4 projects:

- normal project (nothing special here)
- the wrapper project using tycho maven and copy-dependencies.
  bound copy dependencies to some goal before compile (e.g. generate-resources). Excluded all artefactid which were set as dependency in the MANIFEST.MF.
- a prepare project, which calls the normal project and installs it into the repo. This is needed because the tycho-maven-plugin is bound to validate and it is not possible to call the exec plugin beforehand (at least not easy).
- a multi module project which calls the prepare project before the wrapper project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your local project (which artifact was missed) with "mvm install". It will be deployed in your local repository ($USER_HOME$/.m2/repositories). After this dependency should be resolved.

Alternatively you can "mvn deploy" if you have local company maven repository like Artifactory or Nexus.