# How to provide a log4j.properties to an OSGI Bundle (Eclipse-Plugin)?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, log4j, osgi, slf4j

**Project setup:**

1. Logging-1.0.jar

   - contains a Logger.class which uses slf4j/log4j
   - depends on slf4j-api.jar, slf4j-log4j.jar, log4j.jar
2. LoggingOSGI-1.0.jar

   - wraps the logging project
   - contains an Activator and MANIFEST.MF
   - lib/ contains logging-1.0.jar, slf4j-api.jar, slf4j-log4j.jar, log4j.jar
   - jars from lib/ are added to classpath and packages from logging-1.0.jar are exported
3. SomeBundle-1.2.jar

   - contains an Activator and MANIFEST.MF
   - has a dependency on LoggingOSGI-1.0.jar

Accessing the Logger class from SomeBundle works, but the logging project can't find the log4j.properties (log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger).

**Questions:**

- Where do i have to place the log4j.properties?
- Any ideas what i could try? (already tried: different directories, Eclipse-Buddies, -Dlog4j.configuration as VM argument)
- Would be an extension point, which tells the logging project the location of the log4j.properties, a good solution?

Comment: As a side-note, you may want to checkout [Pax Logging](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging) for logging in OSGi.

Comment: This is not an option, since our complete logic is in a simple jar which uses slf4j for logging. The eclipse plugins are just wrapper for convenience. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670300/tycho-plugin-maven-dependency-plugin-copy-dependencies-from-local-projects-in

Comment: Pax Logging seams to be dead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I last tried this around six years ago, the solution turned to be to create a *fragment bundle* with the *log4j.properties* file, and then to attach that fragment (via the `Fragment-Host` manifest header) to the bundle that loads the logging library ("Logging-1.0.jar," in your case). It felt like a lot of project structure, build time, and deployment overhead for what seems like such a simple goal.

See section 3.14 of the [*OSGi Service Platform Core Specification*](http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release5) for more detail on fragment bundles.

An alternate idea is to consider using the Configuration Admin Service to designate the path to a logging configuration file on disk, outside of your bundles. That would require augmenting your logging library to look up a configuration (or, better, *listen* for one) and then pass that configuration through to the logging implementation.

I would also be remiss to not point out the OSGi Log Service, specified in section 101 of the *OSGi Service Platform Service Compendium*.

Comment: Very good answer, still i believe the SystemProperty solution is simpler and uses the log4j standard for setting the properties file (-Dlog4j.configuration=...)

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem i added this code to the Activator of the LoggingOSGI-1.0 which configures log4j. The file path is taken from a System property: `-Dlog4j.configuration=path/to/log4j.properties`.

Still interested in other approaches or opinions to this solution.

```
private static final String LOG4J_CONFIG_KEY = "log4j.configuration";

public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    Activator.context = bundleContext;

    if (System.getProperties().containsKey(LOG4J_CONFIG_KEY)) {
        String file = System.getProperties().getProperty(LOG4J_CONFIG_KEY);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(file);
    }
}
```